# JQuery not responding?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to create a front page that will slowly fade in a div box containing the main content of the page. For whatever reason, the div won't fade in and instead doesn't show at all... since I'm not sure where the disconnect is here is all of my code:

```
<html> 

<header> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).onload(fuction() {

$("div#homebox").fadeIn(400);


}) 

</script> 

<style> 
#homebox {

    background-color: #e0ecf3;
    opacity: 0.8;
    Padding: 50px; 
    Position: center fixed; 
    Margin-top: 100px;  
}
</style> 

</header>

<body> 
        <div id="homebox" hidden>

<p> Welcome to my website. </p>  

        </div>      

</body> 

</html>
```

I'm brand new to working with Jquery so detailed explanations would be the most helpful!

Comment: You may want to create your example in https://jsfiddle.net/ .  This will allow others to see your code, play with it as well as help you get the code live and working when and example is given back to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I load the code into jsfiddle it works, but I can't get it to work outside of jsfiddle in notepad++

Comment: Here is a link to the jsfiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/nb5wum3r/#&togetherjs=5f4p8BVh90

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I left out the n in function. Spell checkers help folks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, please see updates below:

a. Updated `jQuery` cdn link:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

b. Replaced `.onload` function with `.ready`

```html
<style> 
#homebox {
  background-color: #e0ecf3;
  opacity: 0.8;
  Padding: 50px; 
  Position: center fixed; 
  Margin-top: 100px;  
}
</style> 
<body> 
  <div id="homebox" hidden>
    <p> Welcome to my website.</p>  
  </div> 

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#homebox").fadeIn(400);
  }) 
  </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```